# Convergence of sum of reciprocals of $(n!)!$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

To what real number does the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n!)!}$$ converge?
I know that it will converge to a number less than $e$.

Comment: What have you tried? By the least, I would expect to see some approximation, with an additional inquiry whether or not this approximation is a known constant.

Comment: I doubt it is any "particular" number. You can compute a numeric approximation and look it up at https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: The approx. Value is$2.501388889$.

Comment: @quid I got value $2+\frac{361}{720}$ from https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: Yes, me too. I wrote it up as an answer putting it into context. Unfortunately it's not interesting as it is just the exact sum up to $n=3$.

Comment: The number $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)!}$ is irrational.  The proof of that is similar to the proof that $e$ is irrational: Its terms decay too rapidly to be rational.

Answer (score 2):

The sum converges very fast. I do not think it is related to any well-known constant.  Looking it up in the Inverse Symbolic Calculator one draws a blank. The result one gets proposed is 
$$\frac{1801}{720},$$ 
yet that's just the exact value of the sum until $n=3$, thus irrelevant.
Yet, $(4!)!$ has already $24$ decimal digits, and $(5!)!$ almost $200$, so it's pretty close to that rational indeed. But we knew that before.

Comment: Are there any resources where I can read something related.

Comment: The closest I can think of are things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant etc

Comment: Already read that long time ago.